# menustrip tool in c sharp

Tags: c#

im trying to work with the menustrip and i have the helpToolStripMenuItem_Click may someone help me the code on how to put the documentation i.e if i click help a new window show appear with documentation like this picture i capture from a vlc help button
[image]

any ideas this is my empty code

```
private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make form (for example with name frm_Help) with RichTextBox and Button
In Richtextbox add all text (read this [Richtextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx))
In button event click add

```
{
   Close();
}
```

Somewhere where you want to show this form add

```
{
   frm_Help frm=new frm_Help;
   frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: For add file you can do this richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf");

Answer (score 1):

To get the same result as in the image you posted, you need to create a new form, put a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx) control to it and load the HTML page with the documentation to this control in the form's initialization code:

```
public HelpForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Docs\readme.html");
  webBrowser1.DocumentText = text;
}
```

Here, the code reads HTML from the **readme.html** file located in the **Docs** subfolder of the folder where the EXE file is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new form, containing all the text you want in it and in helpToolStripMenuItem_Click you should create new instance of that form and show it (as a dialog maybe)

Comment: im having a problem on how to put all the text on a form how can i achieve it im kind of new to csharp

Comment: @MildredShimz You shouldn't learn C# by help-forums, etc... Books, Google and AutoCompletion. Sometimes even just one of them works! Got stuck? Move on to something that suits your level better, and grow from there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new form or add AboutBox and add RichTextbox control.